# Setting specific bits in a number

Tags: javascript, binary, decimal

var d = 7;

in binary: 7 = (111)

What I want to do is to set second place from right to 1 or 0 at disposal,

and return the decimal value.

For example,if I want to make the second 1 to 0,then after process should return a 5,

because 5=(101).

How to implement this in javascript?

**EDIT**

the answer should be something like this:

```
function func(decimal,n_from_right,zero_or_one)
{

}
```

Where decimal is the number to be processed,
n_from_right is how many bits from right,in my example above it's 2.
zero_or_one means to set that specific bit to 0 or 1 at disposal.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way to clear a bit, is to use the and operation with it's bit complement.

```
7 =  0000000000000111
~2 = 1111111111111101
& :  0000000000000101
```

In code:

```
var d = 7, mask = 2;
d &= ~mask;
```

To set a bit instead of clearing it, you use the or operator instead:

```
d |= mask;
```

If you need to create the mask dynamically to handle different bits, you start with the value one (binary 0000000000000001) and shift the bit to the correct index. The second bit has index one (the rightmost bit has index zero), so:

```
var index = 1;
var mask = 1 << index;
```

Comment: Am I misunderstanding? `~2 !== parseInt("1111111111111101", 2)`

Comment: @MichaelTheriot: I simplified a bit in the answer, the bitwise operators works on 32 bit numbers, so it should be another 16 1's to be accurate. However, the numbers are still not the same, because `~2` is `-3` and `parseInt("11111111111111111111111111111101", 2)` is `4294967293`. As the bitwise operators works on 32 bit numbers, and `4294967293` is too large to fit in 32 bits, it will be converted to `-3` in the operation. (Well, it's really converted to the binary representation of the number, but it comes out as `-3` when converted back.)

Answer (score 11):

One way to do it, but you'd probably be better using bitwise operators

```
var d = 7;
var binary = d.toString(2);

binary = binary.split('');
binary[1] = "0";
binary = binary.join('');
binary = parseInt(binary,2);
```

Comment: I agree bitwise arithmetic is best, but +1 for pointing out the relatively little-known way to convert to/from binary strings.

Answer (score 1):

To set the second bit, simply OR with 2 (10 in binary)

```
var d=5;
var mask=2;
var second_bit_set=d | mask;


          d: 101
       mask: 010
 --------------------
 bitwise OR: 111
```

To remove the second bit, you want to AND with a value which has all bits set, apart from the second one. An easy way to construct this value is to perform bitwise NOT on the value, e.g. ~2

```
var d=7;
var mask=~2;
var second_bit_unset=d & mask;

           d: 111
        mask: 101
 --------------------
 bitwise AND: 101
```

See this [bitwise operator reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) for more information on these operators.

Answer (score 1):

/**
 Convert a decimal number to binary
 **/

```
var toBinary = function(decNum){
    return parseInt(decNum,10).toString(2);
}
```

/**
 Convert a binary number to decimal
 **/

```
var toDecimal = function(binary) {
    return parseInt(binary,2).toString(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using bitshifting:

```
d &~(1<<1)
```

see also [this docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Javascript bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators):

```
var five = 7 & ~2;
```

2 = 10 in binary

Comment: ~ is bitwise NOT - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7e_%28Bitwise_NOT%29

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="XXX\tYYYYYYY\n";
for(var i=0;i<=7;i++){
str+=(i+8).toString(2).substring(1)+"\t"+(i*11+22+128).toString(2).substring(1);
str+="\n";
}
console.info(str);
```

you can make a func from my bike